# CONFIG_GPIO_SYSFS makes /sys/class/leds disappear

Tags: embedded, io, sysfs

I have an embedded Linux board I'm working on, with a button and a couple LEDs.

By default, I can control the LEDs via

```
/sys/class/leds/redled/brightness
```

However, I have no way to monitor the button.  If I enable CONFIG_GPIO_SYSFS, I can't see the LEDs anymore - /sys/class/leds/ is empty.  Additionally, the GPIOs that in theory should go to the LEDs don't do anything, so I can't even hack it.

Any thoughts on how I could get both of these working?

Answer (score 0):

Solution turned out to be simple enough.  It turned out I was poking the wrong GPIO.  The beginning offset was defined in:

```
$LINUX/arch/arm/mach-at91/include/mach/gpio.h
```

as:

```
#define PIN_BASE    NR_AIC_IRQS
```

NR_AIC_IRQS is defined in irqs.h in the same directory as:

```
#define NR_AIC_IRQS 32
```

The pins I was looking for were PB12 and PB13, which I found in gpio.h defined as:

```
#define AT91_PIN_PB12   (PIN_BASE + 0X20 + 12)
#define AT91_PIN_PB13   (PIN_BASE + 0X20 + 13)
```

So the pins I was looking for were 32 + 32 + 12 = 76 and 77.

Comment: Is it normal behaviour for the led class to be disabled if GPIO_SYSFS is enabled?